# Unbold a \boldsymbol in mathmode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, bold

I want to create a `command` that get an unbold character from a boldsymbol in mathmode.

In my setup every vector is in bold font for example `$\boldsymbol{x}$` and the command `\coef{\boldsymbol{x}}{i}` I want to create is for writing the i-th coefficient of this vector and should result in `$x_i$` with normal font. I would like to be able to use it for any vector (which are all boldsymbols).

I tried the `$\mathnormal$` command as shown in the code but it does not do anything.

So is it possible to unbold a boldsymbol in math mode?

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\newcommand{\x}{\boldsymbol{x}}
\newcommand{\coef}[2]{\mathnormal{#1}_{#2}}

\begin{document}
The vector $\x$ and its coefficients $\coef{\x}{i}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should load `bm`, which features a much better implementation of `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: I actually already tried to use this package but, I faced the same problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\boldsymbol` is still inside `\mathnormal`, thus the setting of `\mathnormal` is overwritten by `\boldsymbol`. A way to solve this is to redefine `\boldsymbol` inside `\coef`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\newcommand{\x}{\boldsymbol{x}}
\newcommand{\coef}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\boldsymbol}[1]{##1}%
    #1_{#2}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
The vector $\x$ and its coeficients $\coef{\x}{i}$.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks that working fine, although I don't really get what exactly means `\renewcommand*{\boldsymbol}[1]{##1}%`, in particular why the `*` and what means the 2 # in `##1`.

Comment: @TonioBonnef The star form does not allows paragraphs (`\par`) as argument. And `#` needs to be doubled inside the definition of another command.

Answer (score 8):

A variant of Heiko's method; I also use `bm`, that features a better implementation of `\boldsymbol` (that can also be called `\bm`). With `\ifcoef` you can disable `\boldsymbol` more easily also in other situations, by simply setting `\coeftrue` (in a group).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}

\newif\ifcoef
\newcommand{\bvec}[1]{%
  \ifcoef #1\else\bm{#1}\fi
}
\newcommand{\coef}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \coeftrue
    {#1}_{#2}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\x}{\bvec{x}}

\begin{document}
The vector $\x$ and its coefficients $\coef{\x}{i}$.

The vector $\bvec{\Gamma}$ and its coefficients
$\coef{\bvec{\Gamma}}{i}$

\end{document}
```

[image]