# How to unbold a section of a \boldmath or \boldsymbol?

Tags: color, boldmath

I have some locally defined commands such as

```
\newcommand{\cosx}[1]{\color{blue}\boldsymbol \cos^{#1} x}
```

and I would like to be able to unbold some part of it. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this than by repeating the commands as in:

```
\newcommand{\cosx}[1]{{\color{blue}\boldsymbol \cos}^{#1} {\color{blue}\boldsymbol x}}
```

e.g. some way of wrapping the section to be formatted normally?

I saw [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263040/unbold-a-boldsymbol-in-mathmode), but I believe that issue is actually more complicated as it feeds a bolded symbol into a new command; moreover, the solutions presented are beyond my ability to generalize to other situations (i.e. my question could be generalized to 'how to exempt a section in math mode from formatting (bold, colour, font etc)?').

Comment: `\unboldmath`, perhaps?

Comment: thanks, but this wouldn't work for the colours or fonts, & does not appear to work for the bold, either...

Comment: `\boldsymbol` takes an argument so in your example it only applies to `\cos` how can you unbold only part of that?

Comment: the first command has the `\boldsymbol` apply to everything i.e. `\cos^{#1} x`; the 2nd is a hacked version showing the effect I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want (not sure why)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareMathOperator{\bcos}{\textcolor{blue}{\mathbf{cos}}}
\newcommand{\bx}{\textcolor{blue}{\bm{x}}}

\begin{document}

$\bcos^2\bx$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want the `\cosx` macro, add

```
\newcommand{\cosx}[1]{\bcos^{#1}\bx}
```

Comment: This achieves the desired effect (I am a teacher & do extensive colour-coding in my notes to help students follow steps and see the most important info), but seems to me a variation on what I posted. Is there nothing like `$\bm{\cos x \cdot \normalmath{\sin x} \cdot \cos x} = \cos^{\bm{2}}x \cdot \sin x` where everything inside `\normalmath{ }` would be rendered in default font-style?

Comment: & is there any reason to use \DeclareMathOperator{} over \newcommand for the blue / bold cos(x)? Would be interested to learn more if you can point me in the right direction. Thank you kindly for all your help!

Comment: @RaxAdaam The main reason is that as an operator, the symbol gets the right spacing.

Comment: thank you - that is enormously helpful to know & stands to simplify a lot of the local commands I've implemented.